# Flutter - facebook app events android error

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, kotlin, facebook-events

I install the package facebook_app_events version **0.13.5** that includes the latest facebook sdk. The problem is that when I try to log an event or get an anonymous Id it throws a kotlin exception.
I upgrade my kotlin version to 1.5.31 also I try with flutter clean.

This is my code, I initialize FacebookAppEvent at the top of my widget like the code example.

```
facebookAppEvents.logEvent(
  name: 'button_clicked',
  parameters: {
    'button_id': 'registe_buttonr',
   },
);
```

This is the error:

````
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property anonymousId has not been initialized
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at id.oddbit.flutter.facebook_app_events.FacebookAppEventsPlugin.handleGetAnonymousId(FacebookAppEventsPlugin.kt:82)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at id.oddbit.flutter.facebook_app_events.FacebookAppEventsPlugin.onMethodCall(FacebookAppEventsPlugin.kt:55)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:84)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:865)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events(16052):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)```
````

Comment: I found the answer to this question in this stackoverflow answers
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271507/facebook-app-events-not-working-in-flutter)